# How to create a file in the directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, nul

My dirctory is `D:\\Main`. I want to create a file named `file.js` in the directory only i.e. `D:\\Main`. I use the code
`type nul > file.js`. It creates the file but also displayes an error message saying that `nul` folder wasn't found. Am I doing something wrong? How do I improve the code to stop the error message?

Comment: New-Item -Path "D:\Main\file.js"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you attempted to use is valid for CMD.EXE, but in PowerShell, `type` is an alias for `Get-Content`, which expects a valid device or file. However, the null device is *not* available in PowerShell, although a *variable* `$null` will return the desired value. You should instead use

```
New-Item -Path . -Name "file.js" -Value $null
```

or

```
Set-Content -Path .\file.js -Value $null
```

to create an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get a satisfactory answer so I searched the command list for PowerShell on Microsoft's website.

Use

```
Set-Content -path D:\\Main\file.js
```

Then it will ask for values *(e.g. [-Value0], [-Value1], ...)." Values are what what you want to type in the file e.g. [-Value0] will contain what will be in the first line of the code of file.js. Pressing enter will move to next line i.e. [-Value1]. Pressing enter without typing anything in a value will exit taking values and save the file.

The above command can be shortened like:
`sc` for `Set-Content` & `.` for `D:\\Main` because it is your default directory. You can also skip the `-path` term. So the new shortened command will be:

```
sc .\file.js
```